# Databricks Python find notebook name, cell number and line number

Tags: python, azure-databricks

I am writing a loog tool for Databricks in a custom made class. I therefore need to find the cell number and line number that the script is currently on.

I managed to find the notebook name.

**sentry-log.py:**

```
__notebook = dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().notebookPath().get()
__command_cell = "?"
__line = "?"
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [official documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#list-available-utilities), below is the list of available utilities.

```
dbutils.fs provides utilities for working with FileSystems. Most methods in this package can take either a DBFS path (e.g., "/foo" or "dbfs:/foo"), or another FileSystem URI. For more info about a method, use dbutils.fs.help("methodName"). In notebooks, you can also use the %fs shorthand to access DBFS. The %fs shorthand maps straightforwardly onto dbutils calls. For example, "%fs head --maxBytes=10000 /file/path" translates into "dbutils.fs.head("/file/path", maxBytes = 10000)".

fsutils

cp(from: String, to: String, recurse: boolean = false): boolean -> Copies a file or directory, possibly across FileSystems
head(file: String, maxBytes: int = 65536): String -> Returns up to the first 'maxBytes' bytes of the given file as a String encoded in UTF-8
ls(dir: String): Seq -> Lists the contents of a directory
mkdirs(dir: String): boolean -> Creates the given directory if it does not exist, also creating any necessary parent directories
mv(from: String, to: String, recurse: boolean = false): boolean -> Moves a file or directory, possibly across FileSystems
put(file: String, contents: String, overwrite: boolean = false): boolean -> Writes the given String out to a file, encoded in UTF-8
rm(dir: String, recurse: boolean = false): boolean -> Removes a file or directory

mount

mount(source: String, mountPoint: String, encryptionType: String = "", owner: String = null, extraConfigs: Map = Map.empty[String, String]): boolean -> Mounts the given source directory into DBFS at the given mount point
mounts: Seq -> Displays information about what is mounted within DBFS
refreshMounts: boolean -> Forces all machines in this cluster to refresh their mount cache, ensuring they receive the most recent information
unmount(mountPoint: String): boolean -> Deletes a DBFS mount point
updateMount(source: String, mountPoint: String, encryptionType: String = "", owner: String = null, extraConfigs: Map = Map.empty[String, String]): boolean -> Similar to mount(), but updates an existing mount point instead of creating a new one
```

Regarding Cell number or line number no information is given.